# How do I add a JSON Request file to my project?

Tags: android, json, google-api

I am trying to implement the Google Translation API into my project. While reading the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started?csw=1). It says to

> Create a JSON request file with the following text, and save it as a translate-request.json plain text file like this:

```
  {
'q': 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.',
'source': 'en',
'target': 'es',
'format': 'text'
}
```

How do I go about doing this and where in my project would I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the docs you linked are only an example, that explains how the API works. But it is unrelated to Android development.
As you probably want to query more than one sentence: In real code you would generate the json data as string on the fly. In Java there is the [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) ([tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)).

But a better way is to use one of the Java client libraries that does all that work for you. The docs you linked to had another link to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate-translate-text-java), (next to the code click on Java). And [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) is how to install the client lib.

Comment: Thanks, are you familiar with translating strings in java using the Google Translation API?

Comment: Perhaps you can answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748640/google-api-translate-error-retrieving-translation

Comment: Sorry, I never used the translation API myself. But I have used many REST APIs (which is why I answered this question).

Answer (score 0):

The example is a json file stored on your default IDE folder for your projects. Then you continue with the next step using docs guideline.